# align form in html left and right

Tags: html, css

```
<ul  style="display:inline;width:20cm;">

<li style="display:inline;"><form action={4} >
<input style="color: black;     
    background-color: #3CB371;
    width: 100px;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
    border-radius:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    " type="button" value="Approve"  ></form></li>


    <li style="display:inline;"><form action={5}>
    <input  style="margin-left:80px;
    color: black;
    background-color:   #ff0000;
     width: 100px;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
    border-radius:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    " type="button" value="Reject"  id="buttonReject"></form></li>
    </ul><br><br><br>
```

With this code i am getting the two button forms up and down, but instead i want them right and left ,what changes do i have to make?

Comment: inside ul u can see two forms are there embedded in a botton

Comment: 20cm? Who uses `cm` in web design? Is this going to be printed?

Comment: @Paulie_D Never mind, this is kinda ancient 1980's design. Let's help him in simple ways. LoL.

Comment: @Paulie_D What's wrong with `cm`? I can understand some people prefer the metric system: if you use `px` then you're using `inches` (since there should be 96 pixels per inch, although not all clients will have this correctly implemented).

Comment: @herman Isn't it `72`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, that is `pt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's a `block` or `inline-block` element inside the `<li>`, which is currently `inline` and that would cause the `inline` not to work. So try this instead:

```
<li style="display: inline-block;">
```

**Working Snippet**

```html
<ul style="display:inline;width:20cm;">

  <li style="display:inline-block;">
    <form action={4}>
      <input style="color: black;     
    background-color: #3CB371;
    width: 100px;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
    border-radius:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    " type="button" value="Approve">
    </form>
  </li>


  <li style="display:inline-block;">
    <form action={5}>
      <input style="margin-left:80px;
    color: black;
    background-color:   #ff0000;
     width: 100px;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:15px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
    border-radius:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    " type="button" value="Reject" id="buttonReject">
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `display:inline` to `display:inline-block;`

```
<li style="display:inline-block;">
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v623c32b/)**